# tf.strings.operations raises TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType string not in list of allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a superficial layer to pre-process data inside models. Here is an my Layer:

```
class StringLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(StringLayer, self).__init__()

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.strings.join([some_python_function(word) for word in tf.strings.split(tf.strings.as_string(inputs), sep=" " )], separator=" ")
    
  

#model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
#model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
#model.add(StringLayer())
```

But it keeps giving me: **`TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType string not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64, bfloat16, uint16, float16, uint32, uint64, complex64, complex128, bool, variant`**

*I know I can do this thing out of the model, but my main goal is to somehow do this inside the model; this way, I'll be able to maximize the GPU utilization.*

Comment: From the commented lines, it seems like an input tensor with `dtype=tf.string` is passed to _StringLayer_. Inside this layer, the input tensor is passed to `tf.strings.as_string`, while `as_string` does not accept a string input. For acceptable dtypes see: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/as_string#args

Comment: The code does not run as is, but the problem seems to be resolvable by removing `tf.strings.as_string`.

Comment: @learner how would you split it if it's not even string; as it is being passed through a model, it will become some kind of `Tensor` for sure...

it would be really helpful, if you could simply share your work as a gist in colab, or some where else...